# How call dll from unpaked extension directory

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

We developed dll and using it in our extension (addon-sdk,c-types). But how we can call it after extension install?
By default dll searching in firefox directory, windows and system32 and not in extension folder. How  we can call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `LoadLibraryW`  with a full path to your dll. See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16384129/915844) by @WladimirPalant